# Reemplazar caracteres especiales

Tags: php, string, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo un archivo en php que me busca archivos dentro de un directorio ( carpeta ) el archivo se llama (#archivo#ejemplo.mp3) y el link de ese archivo es guardado en un array

```
 $files[] = array(
                    "name" => $f,
                    "type" => "folder",
                    "path" => $dir . '/' . $f,
                    "items" => scan($dir . '/' .  $f) // <-- aqui es donde me obtiene el link para acceder, necesito reemplazar los caracteres # por _
```

podrian ayudarme... Gracias

Comment: Puedes usar la funcion  str_replace() por ejemplo: $f= str_replace("#", "_", "#archivo#ejemplo.mp3");

Answer (score 3):

Lo puedes hacer con la función [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)

```
echo str_replace("#","_","un#archivo#mio"); // Salida: un_archivo_mio
```

**[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f1f0a3f7f337c35f5d059183b62e6e123c753e8a)**

Comment: no conocía este "code tester" http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ buena aportación!

Comment: Vaya! tampoco conocía ese code tester...